# Can't use an object inside initialize (GameController) method passed from ParametreController to GameController in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm facing a problem with JavaFX. I'm working on a game.
In GameController I'm instantiating a gridPan of 5X5 button and I want to get before that the Parametres of the Game. For example, the Symbol X or O and the opponent if he is human or a robot.

```
package Controlleur;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import Model.Parametre;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

import Model.Grille;

public class GameControlleur implements Initializable {

    private Parametre gameParametre  ;

    private Grille g = Grille.getInstance() ; ;

    @FXML
    private GridPane GrilleV ;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
```

//when i use gameParametre Object here i got error
                initGrille();

```
    }


    public void initParametre(Parametre g) {

        gameParametre = new Parametre(g.getAdversaire(),g.getSymbole() ) ;

    }



    public void initGrille() {

        for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {

            for(int j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j++) {

               if((i > 0 && i < 4) && (j > 0 && j < 4)) {
                    addButton(i,j,true);
                }else{
                    addButton(i,j,false);
                }

            }
         }

        g.initGrille();

      }



     private void addButton(int x , int y , boolean disabled) {

       final Button btn = new Button();

           btn.setMinSize(68, 75);
           btn.setText(" ");

           if(disabled == true) {
             btn.setDisable(true);
           }

            btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

              @Override
              public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                    btn.setText("X");

              }

            });

             GrilleV.add(btn, x, y);

        }


}
```

and this is my ParametreController

```
package Controlleur;

import java.io.IOException;

import Model.Parametre;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ParametreControlleur {



    @FXML
    private RadioButton RdBtnRobot ;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton RdBtnHumain ;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton SymboleX ;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton SymboleO ;
    @FXML
    private Button Quitter ;

    //default choice 
    private String selectedAdversaire = "Robot";
    private String selectedSymbole = "X" ;




    //getting Adversaire
    public void getSelectedAdversaire(ActionEvent e) {

         if(RdBtnRobot.isSelected()) {

             selectedAdversaire =   RdBtnRobot.getText() ;

         }

         if (RdBtnHumain.isSelected()){

             selectedAdversaire = RdBtnHumain.getText() ;

         }

      } 

  //getting Symbol
   public void getSelectedSymbole(ActionEvent e) {

       if(SymboleX.isSelected()) {

           selectedSymbole =  SymboleX.getText() ;

         }

        if(SymboleO.isSelected()){

             selectedSymbole = SymboleO.getText() ;

         }

   }


   @FXML
   public void onCommencer(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {

       //Les parametres de jeu => type d'adversaire choisi ainsi que le Symbole

       Parametre p = new Parametre(selectedSymbole , selectedAdversaire) ;

       FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader() ;
       fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../Vue/game.fxml"));
       Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
        //this is the object that i pass to Gameontroller and i want to retrieve in initialize method
       GameControlleur controller = fxmlLoader.getController() ;
       controller.initParametre(p);

       Stage stage = new Stage();
       stage.setResizable(false);
       stage.setTitle("Quixo");
       stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));  
       stage.show();
       ((Node)(e.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();

   }
```

}

thank you in advance , i appreciate any kind of help or suggestion to solve this problem

Comment: `initialize` runs before `FXMLLoader`'s `load` method returns. The only way of getting hold of the controller before that is constructing the controller yourself and using `setController` or setting the cotrollerfactory before loading. Not sure this would fix the issue though, since you haven't mentioned what exactly goes wrong in your code. You didn't post `Model.Grille`. Btw: By convention package names start with lowercase letters; This makes telling the point where the packages end and the class name(s) begin easier to identify...